# How to refactor a python singleton heavy app?

Tags: python

I've written an app that works well / serves its purpose - but didn't account for growth.

I have heavy dependency on 8 or so classes that are singleton (as i've come to learn), such as this (just one example):

```
class BaseQuotes(np.recarray):
    def __new__(cls, shape=None, dtype=None, order='C'):
```

and later:

```
Quotes = BaseQuotes()
```

And, anywhere I import quotes (a lot of places! Guess that VSCode replace will be needed if i refactor :)), i can call:

```
Quotes.referencePrice()
```

Which was great to get to where i am.

But of course now, i need two (or more!) "Quotes" sets- to hold maintain their own data independent from the other, for reference in additional instances.

Can anyone put me onto a resource to learn how to refactor this, what is my alternative pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: `numpy.recarray` is not inherently 'singleton', so it's unclear what you mean by 'classes that are singleton' in this context? If you defined `BaseQuotes` yourself to be singleton and now you need more of it, that prompts the question why it was singleton to begin with and what is lost if you remove that restriction?

Comment: `Quotes` -> `quotes` please

Comment: Using `__new__` does not automatically make your class into a singleton, it only intercepts the creation of the object (as opposed to `__init__` that lets the object be created before modifying it). It all depends on what you do within the `__new__` method and that you do not show here.